# Article before word "Vacuum"

Tags: articles

[image: Article]
Is it necessary to put an article before the word "vacuum" and if necessary, why?

Comment: What is the context in which you're using the word?

Comment: I'm talking about a vacuum in space. That it contains small particles, that it is not emptiness at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases I can think of, if the word is being used as a noun in a sentence, the answer is "yes."

I was required to create **a** vacuum as a science experiment.

Unprotected human beings could only survive for a couple of minutes in **the** vacuum of outer space.